# How to use GROUP BY to retrieve a result set with priority on alphabeticization

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
SELECT * FROM cars;

id      value
1       convertible
2       van
2       wagon
3       scooter
3       segway
```

When I use the `GROUP BY` statement

```
SELECT * FROM cars
GROUP BY id;
```

I get the following result set

```
1   convertible
2   van
3   scooter
```

How can I change the above statement to select the cars.value that come alphabetically last?  For example

```
1   convertible
2   wagon
3   segway
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT min(value) FROM cars
GROUP BY id;

Comment: If the the 2nd column value was created using the CASE syntax, how would I select the `MAX(new_value)` from it? like `SELECT id, CASE WHEN value=something THEN ELSE 'something' END AS new_value FROM cars`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT * from cars order by value desc
) as tmp
group by id
```

Sorts the table before grouping

[Working example here](http://www.sqlize.com/T59v6ONZzf)

Comment: ManseUK, would the other answer be preferred over yours since this is a nested query and it may be resource inefficient? In my actual table I'm selecting 8 fields.