# How to use GROUP BY to retrieve a result set with priority on alphabeticization for CASE field?

Tags: mysql

In a previous question I asked, someone suggested the `MAX(value)` syntax to prioritize on alphbetization

[How to use GROUP BY to retrieve a result set with priority on alphabeticization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313037/how-to-use-group-by-to-retrieve-a-result-set-with-priority-on-alphabeticization)

However I'm dealing with the `CASE` statement and using `MAX(CASE statement)` is syntactically incorrect.

```
SELECT id, 
CASE
    WHEN filename LIKE '%.mp3' THEN 'song'
    ELSE 'other' END as type
FROM filenames

1   song
2   song
2   other
3   other
3   song

SELECT id, 
CASE
    WHEN filename LIKE '%.mp3' THEN 'song'
    ELSE 'other' END as type
FROM filenames
GROUP BY id;

1   song
2   song
3   other
```

How would I prioritize the `type` field for those which come alphabetically last?  Ex. the result set should be

```
1   song
2   song
3   song
```

I'd like to avoid nested statements if possible.  Can this be done with the `MAX(type)` syntax?

Comment: I believe `MAX(CASE ...) AS sth` is ok, at least using recent mysql ver, whats your error message?

Comment: My bad, I did `MAX(CASE...AS sth)` instead of `MAX(CASE...) AS sth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following

```
SELECT id, 
CASE
    WHEN filename LIKE '%.mp3' THEN 'song'
    ELSE 'other' END as type
FROM filenames
GROUP BY id DESC;
```

DESC will give you descending order